# tar: eosPT_data: Cannot utime: Function not implemented

Tags: ubuntu, tar, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mesa

I am currently trying to install MESA on Windows by using the Windows subshell and Ubuntu. However I am getting this error message:

> tar: eosPT_data: Cannot utime: Function not implemented
>
> tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
>
> FAILED

Has anybody an idea why this is not working ?

Cheers

Comment: Can you add the link of that tar file?

Comment: Yeah sure, its located in /mnt/d/MESA, but I also tried to install it in the home directory and it did not work eigher.

Answer (score 0):

utime not implemented in WSL1.

This is fixed in WSL2 and I believe currently available with windows insider release build 18890.

https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/307

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2019/05/01/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-18890/